# WPF DataTrigger in C# comparing to null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I'm writing a WPF `DataTrigger` in C# and want the trigger to fire when the value is null. However, if I set the `DataTrigger.Value` property to null, the trigger is fired for all bindings. When sticking a converter between the binding and the trigger, I verify that a value of null is passed in, so the `DataTrigger` should be getting it. My `DataGrid` contains integers and if I instead set the value to an integer, it successfully executes my trigger when the numbers match.

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // disable null cells
    var boundColumn = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (boundColumn != null)
    {
        var binding = boundColumn.Binding as Binding;
        if (binding != null)
        {
            var style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
            var dataTrigger = new DataTrigger
            {
                Binding = new Binding(binding.Path.Path)
                {
                    TargetNullValue = binding.TargetNullValue
                },
                Value = null
            };

            dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.IsEnabledProperty, false));
            style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
            boundColumn.CellStyle = style;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code executes the trigger (sets `IsEnabled` to false) for all rows. I also tried changing Value to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` and hit the same issue. If I change Value to 0, it disables all cells that contain a 0. I tried hacking around this by writing a converter that checks for null and returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` but that seems to never execute the trigger. Do I have to define my own object for null and return it for all null values via my converter? That seems super hacky.

EDIT: Fixed code.

Comment: This is not valid C#; please post your real code...

Comment: I just tried the code, it simply disables the cells with null value. seems like it is working as you expect it to be.

Comment: @Sheridan: I do know how to use XAML. I cannot use XAML here because I am using AutogenerateColumns = true. There is no way to customize column behaviors/bindings in XAML when using that property.

Comment: @pushpraj: Hmm, I wonder if there is something else in my system which is causing it to screw up.

Comment: I am sure this is not a system issue. could you post a working sample which can reproduce the same? We may try to find it for you.

Comment: Removing `TargetNullValue` seemed to fix it. I will see if I can get a working failure when I have time.